# How to count values that exist in other column within a range in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have table 1 with OrderIDs and CallIDs and table 2 with CallIDs (that are referenced in table 1) and callDates, how can I find the number of orders within a given date range?

[image: See image of tables]

I believe what I need to do is get the calls that are within a date range in table 2, then check if the CallIDs exist in table 1, then get the count of the result. I just do not know how to put it all together in a formula. For instance in the picture, the number of orders in February should be 3.

Comment: Please provide data in text form, anyone wanting to help shouldn't need to refer to image, and retype all those values.

Comment: Also, please further explain why February should return 3. I count 4 call dates within Februari `=COUNTIFS(E2:E15,"<="&DATE(2022,2,1),E2:E15,"<"&DATE(2022,3,1))`

Comment: @P.b looking at the data I'm guessing it's because call ID 7 does not exist in table 1. Leaving only three calls with valid call id's.

Comment: @JvdV that could just be an explanation. In that case this could be used: `=SUM(COUNTIFS(E2:E15,">="&DATE(2022,2,1),E2:E15,"<"&DATE(2022,3,1),D2:D15,B2:B8))` or Sumproduct

Comment: @JvdV that seems to have worked, thank you!

Comment: The first or last?

Comment: @P.b sorry got your names mixed up, JrdV was right about callID 7 not being in table 1, leaving 3, then your last answer using `=SUM(COUNTIFS())` was correct

Comment: I answered it as an answer so not everyone will open this question as it looks unanswered. Also explained how the calculation works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(E2:E15,">="&DATE(2022,2,1),E2:E15,"<"&DATE(2022,3,1),D2:D15,B2:B8))
```

COUNTIFS creates an array of 0's and 1's (respectively FALSE and TRUE) for the date range in column E containing values greater than or equal to February 1st and smaller than March 1st and where the call number from column D is found in column B.
SUM adds up the 1's and 0's resulting in your count of matches in that range.